# uvcdynctrl can't switch between two cameras in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am working on stereo vision for which i am in the starting phase and want to work with two logitech cameras having pan/tilt functionality. I am able to work the uvcdynctrl together with libwebcam to access the full functionality of one cam but i can't switch to the other cam using uvcdynctrl -d video1 (where video0 is the first one). After doing that it still access the first one. I am not sure of what is wrong here as everything works fine with one cam. 
uvcdynctrl -l gives me this output.

Listing available devices:
  video1   UVC Camera (046d:0994)
    Media controller device /dev/media1 doesn't exist
ERROR: Unable to list device entities: Invalid device or device cannot be opened. (Code: 5)
  video0   UVC Camera (046d:0994)
    Media controller device /dev/media0 doesn't exist
ERROR: Unable to list device entities: Invalid device or device cannot be opened. (Code: 5)

I am using ubuntu 12.04.
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. thanks.